# How many percentage of anime viewers are programmers?

Tags: culture

Anime tend to become more and more popular in Western countries year by year and were always popular in Japan. While many people watch them, seems like most of the fans are geeks or gamers.

Based on the above, is it true, a huge percentage of programmers like anime?

While there are anime fans everywhere, most fans are from either USA or Japan. To make the question more specific, I am asking about those two countries.

Comment: I think this may be the wrong place to ask that question as per the [FAQ](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Cole Busby: I checked the FAQ but it's not clear why my question is not appropriate.

Comment: It's subjective; there's no hard facts stating your presumption, nor is it necessarily germane to a discussion about anime/manga in general.

Comment: It's possible there was a survey or study somewhere, though I don't know where'd you go looking for something like that. Is this a question specifically for people in the U.S.? Or Japan?

Comment: @Jon Lin: I am not asking specifically about USA or Japan, of course any survey is better than no survey at all.

Comment: @Luka the question is then [too board](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as an Industry can be different depending on country so *good answers would be too long for this format*, even focusing it on the west in my opinion is too board, however i don't even know where i would begin to answer this question so i will abstain from placing any votes at this time

Comment: @Luka IMHO "Anything not directly related to anime and manga", this is *VERY* loosely tied to Anime if anything the statistics of a Genre in a given occupational field is more the content of this question which again is off-topic.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Anime and or Manga and sounds a bit opinion based.

Comment: Think it is a valid question, but to broad. The terms "Like" and "programmer" are way to broad. Besides that there are no factual answers possible to this question. There for even if made more specific answering is highly unlikely.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Dimitri mx. Valid question but too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are no definite answers possible for your question, as there are no known numbers of anime fans within the programming community.**

Besides that, it is still very Dependent on how broad you take the term *"programmer"* and *"like"*. 
There are plenty of children out there that are able to write a simple script and call them self a programmer. And even without those there are tons of programmers that enjoy watching a anime every once in a while, or some times a cartoon. Which roughly would be just as big as the programmer group that likes to watch a movie, television series and even reading a good book.

We can make a well educated guess, but it would be no more than speculation.
Assuming you are aiming at the above average adult anime watching behavior, so where adult are watching just as much as kids. Which is according to the following source roughly 24 hours a week or 3.4 hours a day.

> According to TV ratings company Nielsen, kids in 2012, age 2 to 11, watched an average of 24 hours of TV a week. That’s an average of three and a half hours a day.

Taking a average daily life of showering, eating and minimum healthy sleeping habits and jobs into account. A person would take up about at least 19 hours a day, leaving 5 hours a day. With the average programmers age of about 37 years this time is usually spend with wife/ kids. Leaving about 13% tops of programmers above the age of 20 to even have time enough to above averagely like anime to begin with.